# How adjust the ratio between the units of axes?

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

Initially I thought that the function AspectRatio-> calibrated the ratio between the units axes, e.g. putting AspectRatio->1/2 I thought that the ratio x:y between units of the axes would be 1:2, but I surprisingly discovered that this is false: indeed, in the following plot

```
f[x_] := ((3/20)^(471/100)*20/29*(x - 80))^(50/
     91) + ((3/20)^(471/100)*20/29*(x - 60))^(50/91) - 1/25
Subscript[x, 0] = Extract[{x} /. FindRoot[f[x] == 0, {x, 80}], 1];
Subscript[P, 0] = Point[{Subscript[x, 0], 0}];
Subscript[G, f] = 
  Subscript[G, f] = 
   Plot[f[x], {x, 80, 100}, PlotStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> 1, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
    PlotLegends -> {LineLegend[{Red}, {"f(x)"}], 
      Placed[Row[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(0\)]\) = (", 
         Round[Subscript[x, 0], .001], ",", 0, ")"}], Below]}];
Show[Subscript[G, f], Graphics[{PointSize[0.015], Subscript[P, 0]}]]
```

[image]

the ratio between the units of the axes is not 1:1.The more relevant problem is that I do not know the ratio between the units of the axes in the image and this is a problem because I have to put it into the graphic. So how calibrate the ratio between the units of the axes? Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: With v12.3.1 on a Mac your code produces a ratio of 1:1 comparing the total axes lengths.

Comment: So you are saying that $$\frac{\text{unit }x}{\text{unit }y}=1$$ right?

Comment: The more relevant problem is that I do not know the ratio between axes in the image and this is a problem because I have to put it into the graphic.

Comment: No, I'm saying the (measured length of the total x axis) == (measured length of the total y axis). If you want the length of 1 unit to be the same on each axis, use `AspectRatio -> Identity`; however, in this case the scales are radically different and this would cause the y axis to be collapsed to a line.

Comment: So I'd like know what is the ratio between units when I put AspectRatio->1 because I have to put it as legend in the image.

Comment: Depending on what the legend is to reflect, `Divide @@ (Subtract @@@ (Reverse /@ (PlotRange /. Cases[Subscript[G, f], _Rule, Infinity])))` or its reciprocal.

Comment: Sorry, I have not understand what you said. Could you explain better, please?

Comment: `(PlotRange /. Cases[Subscript[G, f], _Rule, Infinity])` extracts the `PlotRange`, i.e., `{{80, 100}, {-0.00881036, 0.036832}}`; reversing and subtracting gives the extent of each range, i.e, `{20, 0.0456423}`; and the ratio is `438.19`. If that or its reciprocal is not what you want, I don't understand what you want.

Comment: You have to consider the height and width of the plot. Try `Plot[x*s,{x,0,1},AspectRatio->1,PlotRange->{0,1}]` for various values of s>0 both s<1 and s>1 to see what happens.

Comment: @BobHanlon Okay, I understood: anyway, there is not a way to regulate the ratio x:y, e.g. If I wanted that it shall be 1:1000 what would I have to do?